# Vi issue in hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, vim

as a fresh user in Hadoop, I found that when I connect to the virtualBox I can only use vi. If I type 'vim' it will shows that `-bash: vim: command not found`. So is there anyone who can tell me that how can I use vim in the sandbox? Thank you guys.
PS: I use a Mac,vm information: Name: Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1 , OS: Red Hat(64 bit) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install it first. On CentOS/Red Hat:

```
sudo yum install vim-X11 vim-common vim-enhanced vim-minimal
```

Comment: sorry...I missed that. I use a MAC. let me edit it in the question. thank you

Comment: You're using a mac, but I assume the VM is running CentOS. You should run the command in the VM, not your host machine.

Comment: oh, sorry again...i misunderstand that. make it clear, its Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1 , OS: Red Hat(64 bit)